# Swift3 error 'cannot be applied to operands of type

Tags: ios, swift, casting

Getting the following error:

`Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UInt16' and '() -> UInt16'`

in this section of code:

```
  let array: [UInt16] = [3,4, 7]

  let x = NSNumber(value: 4)
  let option = array.filter { (test) -> Bool in
    return test == x.uint16Value    // compiler complains here
  }
  print(option)   // "[4]"
```

Normally this type of error means two values of separate class are being compared. Here the compiler thinks I'm comparing a uint16 value with a function that returns a uint16 value.

What I mean to do is call NSNumber's uint16 property getter.

```
// defined in NSNumber
open var uint16Value: UInt16 { get }
```

I'm told to instead make a function call by adding parenthesis (e.g `.uint16Value()`). But this leads to the follow up error:

`Cannot call value of non-function type 'UInt16'`

I have dropped this exact code into a playground and it runs fantastically.
Has anyone else run into this? Or seen this type of behavior? Have you beaten it?

Update:

When setting to a local variable, no difference is made. I have recently run the migration tool from Swift 2.2 or 2.3 up to swift 3 in Xcode 8.0. It doesn't seem like there is anything wrong with syntax or migration.

```
let y = x.uint16Value
return test == y    // compiler complains here
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is happening in Swift 3? Errors like this happened quite a bit in Swift 1 & 2. Try assigning `x.uint16Value` to a local variable, and then comparing that variable to `test`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the same result with exactly the same code you have shown above. Reading that _I have dropped this exact code into a playground and it runs fantastically._, your project may have something special -- using third party libraries, having Objective-C code, defining your own extensions... Check your code with a freshly made new project.

Comment: Why the `NSNumber` *detour*? `let x : UInt16 = 4` 
`let option = array.filter { $0 == x }`

Comment: @OOPer I'll drop it into a new project to see what happens.

Comment: @vadian, this is bit of a contrived example. In my app the NSNumber comes from a data source.